# Edit SQL Server CE 3.5 Database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: database, sql-server-ce

I am currently trying to develop an application for windows ce devices. 
Therefore, I have a SQL Server CE database and the plugin by ErikEJ (http://erikej.blogspot.de/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html)

I only want to edit the database, not add it to any project. I used the menu "Extras" --> "Connect to Database" and selected "SQL Server Compact 3.5 (Simple by ErikEJ). Now, there is a Windows showing up, which shows one property "ConnectionString". I add the path (`D:\database\db_example.sdf`) of the local `.sdf` database file and confirm.

But then an error shows up saying:

> The Format of the initializing-string does not start at index 0. Parametername: value

I'm new to this topic and need this database for a project for school, but I can't find information about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the SQL Compact Toolbox window, and connect to the database from the right click menu there instead

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you for your work! I must have been blind today ;)